# Enhancing classes in netbean, DataNucleus

Tags: java, jpa, netbeans, datanucleus

Hi i have a problem with using datanucleus for my JPA

i'm using netbeans as my IDE, i've imported the datanucleus enhancer jar, but everytime I ran the file, it says that i should enhance my class.

I've search the net and i'm still not sure on how to do it, anyone kind enough to shed some light on how to enhance my class in netbeans?

thanks XD

Answer (score 1):

create a -post-compile task which will call datanucleusenhancer task.

http://jkook.blogspot.com/2011/07/netbeans7-integration-with-datanucleus.html

Answer (score 0):

isn't the normal way with Netbeans to just use Ant ? so add build.xml and a step post-compile to enhance your model classes. See 
http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_1_0/guides/netbeans/index.html
for an old guide (Netbeans 4.x, with DataNucleus predecessor JPOX)

Comment: what he's asking is how to use the IDE to automagically do it, like Eclipse does, without manually editing the build files.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Maven2 project, using the wizard and change your pom.xml like explained at

http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/guides/maven2/index.html

You only need one repository.

```
    <repository>
        <id>DataNucleus_Repos2</id>
        <name>DataNucleus Repository</name>
        <url>http://www.datanucleus.org/downloads/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
```